# Perl: Traversing through directories and getting a pattern from a file

Tags: regex, perl, sorting, subdirectory

I am new to Perl. I have to complete a task. I have been given a directory and in that directory has 130 sub directories. From those directories has report sub- directory and from reports, there is one .txt file that I want to grab the pattern from that file.

Similarly, I have to do it for all and get the pattern.

Can anyone please help with sample code or how to do that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: You can't just ask someone to do your entire work for you. Try yourself something and tell us what you did. Now you can ask us about some area at which you are in trouble.

Comment: Take a look at the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module. It covers a good chunk of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Start with this:

```
#!/bin/env perl
use strict; use warnings;

my ($dir) = @ARGV;
$dir // die "No dir supplied";

die "Dir not found: $dir" unless (-e $dir);
die "Not a dir: $dir" unless (-d $dir);

my @files = <$dir/*/txtfile.txt>;

foreach my $file (@$files) {
    my $file_contents = undef;

    # read the patten from file..
    open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Can't open $file. $!";
    # Read the file contents here..
    {
        local $/ = undef;
        $file_contents = <$fh>;
    }
    close $fh;

    # Do something more
}
```

This method is called file globbing. There are better ways using purpose-written modules, but this works in a pinch. It's the same kind of thing as entering `ls -l mydir/*/txtfile.txt` into a terminal window.